# How to change updatedAt value without Doctrine lifecycle callback updating it just after?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, alice-fixtures

Some entities have an updatedAt field which value is well updated through prePersist and preUpdate Doctrine lifecycle callbacks.

But when setting up my project, I populate my db with [AliceDataFixtures](https://github.com/theofidry/AliceDataFixtures) so all fixtures have the same createdAt and updatedAt values.

I was thinking about creating a Symfony command to update this values after fixtures loading in order to get more realistic data. The problem is that it solves only the createdAt issue.

Is it possible to temporary disable Doctrine lifecycle callbacks ?

Can I override its behaviour ?

**Edit:**

All entities use a trait defining 2 methods called by Doctrine lifecycle callbacks.

```php
public function setCreatedAt(): self
{
    $this->createdAt = new DateTimeImmutable();

    return $this;
}

public function setUpdatedAt(): self
{
    $this->updatedAt = new DateTimeImmutable();

    return $this;
}
```

```xml
<lifecycle-callbacks>
    <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="setCreatedAt" />
    <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="setUpdatedAt" />
    <lifecycle-callback type="preUpdate" method="setUpdatedAt" />
</lifecycle-callbacks>
```

I don´t set them in fixtures but if I try as below, the lifecycle callback still changes the value to the current date afterwards.

```yaml
Model\MyEntity:
  entity_{1..30}:
    __construct:
      ...
    __calls:
      - setCustomUpdatedAt: [<pastDateTimeImmutable()>]
```

Comment: Could you share a bit of your Alice fixtures and your `prePersist()`/`preUpdate()` methods ? Maybe checking on the `$updatedAt` during `prePersist()` would be enough.

Comment: Easy: I don't bind the `setUpdatedAt` to `prePersist`. updatedAt shouldn't have a value, unless it is updated; just leave it as null on creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zedling commented, you could simply not call the `setUpdatedAt()` method during `prePersist`.

But if you still want `$updatedAt` to be set automatically on `prePersist` **and** be able to override it in your fixtures, I'd change the `setUpdatedAt` method by

```php
public function setUpdatedAt(): self
{
    // I assumed that your entity has an auto-generated identifier called `$id`
    if (null !== $this->id || null === $this->updatedAt) {
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTimeImmutable();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

If it's an update, the `$id` won't be `null` and `$updatedAt` will be updated. If it's an insert (*persist*), then it will be updated only if it has no value yet. That should let you set it on the fixtures you want.

Here is a demo link: https://3v4l.org/F9dVj

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot ! I prefer keeping a non-null updatedAt